# In N2CMS MVC with Razor, how do you add the Control Panel and Zones?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, n2

If you were using N2CMS MVC with the ASP.NET view engine, you would using the following code to add the Control Panel and a Zone to the page.

```
<n2:SlidingCurtain ID="sc" runat="server">
    <n2:ControlPanel runat="server" EnableEditInterfaceIntegration="false" />
</n2:SlidingCurtain>
<n2:DroppableZone ID="Zone2" ZoneName="Left" runat="server" />
```

Is this even possible using the Razor view engine to enable the drag-n-drop zones?  If so what is the syntax?

I have tried:

```
@{ Html.DroppableZone("Left").Render(); }
@{ Html.RenderZone("Left"); }
```

The above code renders the zone, but I am not sure how to enable the control panel or how to invoke the drag-n-drop style zone editing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out I was close.

Adding the following to the _Layout.cshtml enabled the Control Panel.

```
@{ Html.ControlPanel().Render(); }
```

And using DroppableZone enabled a target for the drag-n-drop.

```
@{ Html.DroppableZone("Left").Render(); }
```

Add the appropriate namespace to make sure the extension methods are available.

```
@using N2.Web.Mvc.Html;
```